# Why does $73|2^9 - 1$ or $1103|2^{29}-1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why does $73|2^9 - 1$ or $1103|2^{29}-1$?
By Fermat's little theorm $73|2^{72}-1$. I wonder why $73\nmid2^8-1$ and $73\nmid{2^{72}-1\over2^9-1}$
I haven't learned about congruence yet, would you mind explain it without using congruence?

Comment: At least for the first one, try using the difference of cubes formula

Comment: Well, I’ve known about congruences for a long time, so I don’t think in the non congruence mode. The crucial fact here is that 73 and 1103 are prime numbers, and the multiplicative groups of the corresponding finite fields are cyclic, of order 72 and $1102=2\cdot19\cdot29$, respectively. Sorry.

Comment: Multiplicative order $ord_{73}(2)=9$, in pari/gp `znorder(Mod(2,73))`;  $ord_{1103}(2)=29$, `znorder(Mod(2,1103))`.